# How to execute projection query in NDB in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine

In 1.7 release NDB got support projection queries, [documentation states](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries?hl=pl#projection) that this is the syntax:

```
qry = Article.query(projection=[Article.author, Article.tags])
```

But running this results in the exception:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'projection'
```

So is there a support for projection queries in the NDB, if yes how to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an error in the documentation, the correct syntax is:

```
qry = Article.query().get(projection=[Article.author, Article.tags])
```

…replace `get` with [method of your choosing](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queryclass?hl=pl) as long as it takes [**q_options](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queryclass?hl=pl#kwdargs_options) arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out how to use from the test case:
http://codereview.appspot.com/6133044/patch/2001/1012

and here: http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/issues/detail?id=181

But remember

`Article.query().get(projection=[Article.author, Article.tags])`
 always return entities, not query. Beside `get`, you can use `fetch(projection=[Article.author, Article.tags])` or `fetch_async(projection=[Article.author, Article.tags])`